# openpyxl not working as EXE

Tags: python, python-3.x, hook, pyinstaller, openpyxl

Error message from running my exe:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

testHi.py

```
#simple test to see if openpyxl module works
import openpyxl

print ("hi")
input()
```

hook-openpyxl.py

```
# taken from pyinstaller dev team, store in same dir as testHi.py 
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

datas = collect_data_files('openpyxl')
```

cmd line input:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=py.ico --additional-hooks-dir=. hiTest.py
```

I run the the hiTest and get the error above.

I have looked everywhere for this solution. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my issue by installing it through Pip, rather than install the package through Pycharm, and Pyinstaller was able to find the package.

I got the idea from looking through the text in the command prompt and saw it was loading modules that I had installed via Pip and not through Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using auto-py-to-exe (which uses pyinstaller) by including the following folders/files from my python library into the same folder that I run pyinstaller from:

- jdcal.py
- openpyxl   (folder)
- et_xmlfile (folder)

pyinstaller command:

```
    pyinstaller -y -F "[directory]/myscript.py"
```

### Notes on Library Location:

Windows library location for me was: C:\users[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib

The packages were in the "site_packages" folder

Answer (score 0):

use
--hiddenimport openpyxl

long with the previous solutions, it worked for me, I was able to enforce the import of openpyxl.

Comment: this doesnt work

Comment: not work for me either!
>> remove and reinstall openpyxl package via pip worked (solution by Takehomasak above)

Answer (score 0):

You was quite close. :-)

I fixed the problem by modifying the "hook-openpyxl.py" file. The command `collect_data_files('openpyxl')` actually returns an empty list. But there is another command `collect_submodules` which seems to do what we want. So my "hook-openpyxl.py" file looks like this.

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('openpyxl')
```

I placed the "hook-openpyxl.py" file in the same directory like my spec file. In the spec file I set to location of the new hook file

```
a = Analysis(
    ...
    ...
    hookspath=['.'],
    ...
    ...
...
```

I guess, you will have the same result with your command line parameter

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=py.ico --additional-hooks-dir=. hiTest.py
```

My environment

- Python=3.8
- openpyxl=3.0.10
- PyInstaller=4.8

Answer (score 0):

@Kallisto
Your answer worked. And command line input of @Gary also worked.
Place the file "hook-openpyxl.py" in the folder where your spec file will be created and then use the command line input.

[image]

This occurs whenever the hook files for the module we are trying to integrate is missing in "\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks".

[image]

You can see that there is hook-openpyxl.py between hook-numpy and hook-packaging.

After running the command line input procced with general steps of pyinstaller.

[image]