# How can I fix python to exe conversion?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Converting my python script to an executable I bump into this error:

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl.utils.dataframe'
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling openpyxl. I have updated it and also tried different converters, `pyinstaller`, `py2exe` and `auto-py-to-exe` but still the same issue.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openpyxl not working as EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50512682/9705687)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the version of your package is still up-to-date. Try to install it via

```
pip3 install openpyxl
```

instead of just `pip`.