# py to exe - missing openpyxl

Tags: python, pyinstaller, openpyxl, py2exe

At the very beginnig of my Python adventure I built simple app using `openpyxl`.
Runs fine in PyCharm.
When I built exe it does not work - in the warning file there is an information: `"missing module named openpyxl"`.
I built exe using:

```
pyinstaller -c -D appname.py , pyinstaller -c -F appname.py
pyinstaller -c -D --hiddenimport openpyxl appname.py
```

none of these worked.

P.S. I can see the following path of `openpyxl` package:

```
C:\Users\(...)\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl
```

PyInstaller: 4.8
Python: 3.10.2
Windows 10

Comment: please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512682/openpyxl-not-working-as-exe

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I read this before.

Comment: The problem fixed after renaming main python file - from standard "main.py" to any other name.

Answer (score 0):

**The following solution worked for me:**

Add the following imports to the `.spec` file:

```
import sys
import openpyxl
```

And add the following hidden imports:

```
hiddenimports=['openpyxl'] + [x for x in sys.modules.keys() if x.startswith('openpyxl.')]
```